# Determine the largest area of an ellipse enclosed by the hyperbolas ($xy=1$ and $xy=-1$)

Tags: integration, conic-sections, area, parametric

> > **Question**: An elipse with equation $$ {x^2\over a^2} + {y^2\over b^2} = 1 $$
> >     is enclosed by the hyperbolas given by $xy=1$ and $xy=-1$. , Determine the largest area of an ellipse enclosed by the hyperbolas. Note that the area of the ellipse is $$ A = πab$$

I know that the answer is $A=2\pi$ by solving it this way:

Considering the hyperbola $y=\frac{1}{x} \Leftrightarrow y^2 = \frac{1}{x^2} $

Now

Ellipse is

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}= 1 $$

$$ x^2b^2 + y^2a^2-a^2b^2=0 $$

$$ x^2b^2 + \frac{a^2}{x^2}-a^2b^2=0$$

$$x^4b^2 - a^2b^2x^2+a^2=0$$

As this is a biquadratic and with the ellipse it appears to be a 4 point symmetric (i.e. tangent) hence discriminant must be equal to zero.

so

$$ b^2-4ac=0$$

$$ a^4b^4-4b^2a^2=0$$

$$ a^2b^2(a^2b^2-4)=0$$

$$ ab = 2 $$

Hence max area is $A=2\pi$

But I was wondering if there is an alternative way of finding out this area through integration or parametric equations, surely there is more than one way?

Comment: @DougM All "touching" ellipses have the same area.

Comment: If you weren't given the area of the ellipse you would have to rely on integration to find the area. When taking the integral you can work out that in general the area is $\pi ab$. So really your work here relies on the integration of the ellipse even though you haven't done it. Also you have only shown that the case that the ellipse shares a point with the hyperbola has a constant area (hens maximum area).

Comment: @WimC  Indeed, I hadn't realized that at the time, but that is absolutely true.

Answer (score 2):

$u = \frac xa\\
v = \frac yb\\
\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1 \to
u^2 + v^2 = 1\\
xy = 1 \to uv = \frac {1}{ab}$

$uv = k$ touches $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ when $k =\frac 12$

For any ellipse that touches the hyperbola, $ab = 2,$ and its area $= 2 \pi$

Comment: Did you mean hyperbola, not parabola?